# Fetching Line number and column number from NVDA plugin

Tags: nvda

Need help to retrieve  current line number and character column from editor based on the cursor position in my NVDA plugin code. Tried using `textInfos` obj but unable to find the information.

Thanks in advance.

```
fObj = api.getFocusObject()

CurrentLine = fObj.makeTextInfo(textInfos.POSITION_CARET)
CurrentLine.expand(textInfos.UNIT_LINE)
```

CurrentLine does not have line and column numbers.